# How to get the server to set content type to text/xml

Tags: xml, http, voip, content-type

I am a newbie with regards to html/xml.

I am trying to get one of the Cisco VoIP phones (7970G) to display my custom directory. The phone is in SIP mode.

When I need to access the custom directory, the phone makes a http request to the specified server and downloads a xml file. This file contains xml tags defined by Cisco and once the file is downloaded it is displayed on the phone.

I set up a http server at home and managed to get this function working successfully. However, when I place the files on my ISPs webserver (personal web space) then it does not work.

I did a line trace and noticed that the only difference in the two scenarios I could notice is the http content type definition. At home, where it works, the http content type is defined as text/xml and when I access the file from ISPs server it is defined as application/xml.

I would appreciate if anyone could suggest a way around this problem. As mentioned my knowledge of http/html/xml is pretty basic so please be specific if you have any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that it was as easy as creating a .htaccess file with the following line in it.

AddType text/xml .xml

However this worked because my ISP has enabled the use of .htaccess file as per the link below.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file